# Identify my bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

How do I find out what my mountain bike is? I bought this mountain bike frame from a friend about a year ago. He told me that it is a specialized frame but I can't find it anywhere on the internet.

[image: Here's my bike]
[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's a bike.  Seems to be absent the rear brakes?

Comment: It looks similar to a Specialized Hardrock that a friend of mine owns...

Comment: This is a difficult one. Use of a bottom pull FD suggests Specialized, but the additional reinforcement on the seat tube looks very much like a Haro Zero. But that doesn't fit either as the seat stay geometry looks like a XC bike. My guess is that it's a mid 00s frame (once discs beacme more prevalent) with parts of an early 00 Fuji or similar (who ran a Jett fork). The fork seems of of place on what seems like a strengthened aggressive frame.

Comment: The reason it doesn't have a rear brake I'm guessing is because the donor bike didn't run discs and this bike doesn't have posts.

Answer (score 7):

Going out on a limb I'll say it's a [Haro Escape](http://www.bikepedia.com/quickbike/BikeSpecs.aspx?Year=2005&Brand=Haro&Model=Escape%208.1&Type=bike#.UnWQ3PlmhcY) frame c2002 - 2005 with donor parts from a c2001 Fuji. Haro's have a decipherable serial number for BMXs so MTB might be similar check [here](http://bmxmuseum.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=206889) to see if that is any help in confirming.

If it was the Haro Escape it could well be a good frame to rebuild with a 150mm fork for a fun AM/FR hardtail.

Comment: That definitely looks right on.

Comment: owning a haro escape, this is not the bike. the haro has a bent/dropped frame towards the seatpost um..
mongoose?
spesh? sick frame, still :)

Comment: The later 2007+ ones did, the top tube was nearly straight through the seat stay.